# Electron: How to print the ZPLCode value of an API response directly to a label printer?

Tags: electron

I have an electron app that I am trying to print to a label printer. I make a request to an external API and I get back a response:

```
ResponsePackage:[
0: {
  AirportCode: "",
  BarCode: "111111111111111111111111111111",
  PackageID: "xxxDEV1057-A",
  ShippingCharge: 0,
  TrackingNumber: "xxx000000380",
  Unicode: "40",
  ZPLCode: "~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the rest of the response code ...
 },
1: { .. another entry with similar format}
]
```

The relevant code in the window that has this response has the following code:

```
      const options = {
        // name: 'ZDesigner GC420d (EPL)',
        silent: false,
        printBackground: false,
        color: false,
        margin: {
          marginType: 'printableArea'
        },
        landscape: false,
        pagesPerSheet: 1,
        collate: false,
        copies: 1
      }

      if (orderCreated) {
       responsePackage.map(puroPackage => ipcRenderer.send('print-job', [options, puroPackage.ZPLCode]) ) // ZLPCode is the code from the response object above
      }
```

In my main.js file, I have the icpMain that reacts to the event:

```
 ipcMain.on('print-job', (event, args) => {
    console.log('args: ', args); // shows the proper ZPLCode passed in

    // how do I print the ZPLCode passed in args?
    mainWindow.webContents.print(args, (success, failureReason) => {
      if (!success) console.log(failureReason);

      console.log('Print initiated')
    })
  })
```

I do not want to print the contents of the mainWindow as this ZPLCode data will not be in the window, but only in memory to be sent to the label printer. How can I print the contents of the ZPLCode if it's not in the window?

Comment: the webcontents.print() function can be used to print the contents in a webpage only. So better look for other modules. or if possible create a new temporary html page out of the json reponse, and load it into a new browserwindow keeping its show:false, and then try to print using the same newbrowserwindow.webcontents.print()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to communicate via `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` and no need to use `webContents.print()` since I am not printing the contents of a window.

To get this to work, I had to install `node-printer` from https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer using `yarn`.

Then I imported the `printer` into my module via `import printer from 'printer';`

Use `console.log('printer.getPrinters: ', printer.getPrinters());` to see what printers are installed on the OS. The one I want to use is named 'ZDesigner GC420d (EPL)'

Then when I got my response back from the external API with the proper ZPLCode:

```
 // ResponsePackage is an array
        ResponsePackage.forEach(package => printer.printDirect({
          printer: 'ZDesigner GC420d (EPL)',
          data: package.ZPLCode,
          type: 'RAW',
          success: (jobID) => {
            console.log("sent to printer with ID: " + jobID);
          },
          error: (error) => console.log('error: ', error)
        }) )

      }
```